# Trying to get rid of repeated indexes in my stack push function. I am using a 2d array to simulate a linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

my stack will print out 25 random indexes including some repeats, im trying to solve my problem of removing any repeated indexes, here is my attempt at working on this issue.

```
    void Push(int value)
            {
                //check if stack is full
                if (myTop == Capacity - 1)
                {
                    std::cout << "The stack is full" << std::endl;
                }

                else
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < Capacity; i++)
                    {
                    Array[myTop] = rand() % Capacity; //generates 25 random indexes

                    //if i have some indexes that repeat
                    if (Array[myTop]== Array[myTop])
                    {
                        Array[myTop] = rand() % Capacity;
                    }
                    std::cout << Array[myTop]<<" #"<<i+1 << std::endl;//prints those 25 random indexes



                    }



                    std::cout << myTop <<": random index"<<std::endl; //prints out the random index my top is stored in
                    std::cout << value <<": value user entered"<<std::endl;//prints out value user wants to push

                }

            }
```

Comment: So..what issue are you facing?Could you elaborate

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all and I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Basically, I have a 2d array that holds 25 indexes, im using this push function to add a value at the top of my stack, and this value is stored in a random valid index in my array. Ex if i push (5) it could be stored randomly at index 7. Currently my issue is that I have repeated indexes ex 2 indexes at 10. Instead of 1 index at 0,1,2,3 etc to 25.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's not clear what `Array` or `myTop` is. To me it looks like you are repeatedly overwriting `Array[myTop]` with a random number 2 times each iteration.

Comment: Like I said before, your code does not make sense. For example, you compared something to itself in the line `if (Array[myTop]== Array[myTop])`. It sounds like you're trying to generate 25 random numbers, each can be 1 to 25 inclusive, without any repeats. In that case, just take an ordered list (1, 2, 3, 4...) and call [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Before using rand(), first you need to initialze it with a seed so that you can different results in each session. Seeding srand with time is a good option. Please include '#include' header and write 'srand(time(NULL));' line before following line in your code:

Array[myTop] = rand() % Capacity; //generates 25 random indexes

Comment: That's not the problem. His code does not make sense.